# How to find out the number of the week in a calculated field?

Tags: 2010, calculated-column

How can I calculate the number of the week based on a date in a list? I tried several examples I found on the internet, but none worked correctly?

The formula should comply with the ISO standard where the week always begins on a Monday, and ISO week 1 begins on the Monday of the first week of the year that contains a Thursday. Said differently, ISO week 1 is the first week (beginning on Monday) that has at least four days.

Anybody has a good solution for that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used the following formula. Week starts on monday. Depending on your regional settings you have to replace the ; with ,

> =IF(INT((StartDate-DATE(YEAR(StartDate);1;1)+(TEXT(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(StartDate);1;1)-1);"d")))/7)=0;52;INT((StartDate-DATE(YEAR(StartDate);1;1)+(TEXT(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(StartDate);1;1)-1);"d")))/7))

Comment: about the regional settings: login with browser locale "en-us". then add this formula in a calculated field, save it. After that,change back the locale ID and the formula automatically replaces with the localized formula.

Comment: Hi Can you suggest me what changes i need to make if my week starts from Sunday rather than Monday, and First week would be the week having Wednesday

Comment: @Flash265 Is it possible to let us know what to change to get it to start from Sunday?

Comment: I found that this formula from @Flash265 works quite well but skips 1 week. For example, running it against 01/jan/2019 returns 52 whether it should return 1. Also, for 31/12/2019 it returns 52 too whether it should return 53. I did this tests running the results against the WeekNum() function on excel, so I've made a little change to it in order to fix that. Here my version:

`=IF(INT((StartDate-DATE(YEAR(StartDate);1;1)+(TEXT(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(StartDate);1;1)-1);"d")))/7)=0;1;INT((StartDate-DATE(YEAR(StartDate);1;1)+(TEXT(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(StartDate);1;1)-1);"d")))/7)+1)`

Answer (score 1):

On the following link a solution is described:

http://www.petestilgoe.com/2009/08/displaying-the-week-number-using-a-sharepoint-calculated-column/

Please keep in mind that different countries handle weeknumbers differently:
week 1 could be:
* the week of 1 january (any day)
* the first week that has at least 4 days of januari
* the first week that has 7 days of januari

Comment: The formula under your link does not seem to work correctly: For example: for 1/1/2012 it returns week 4. It's seems to work for 2011 and 2013, 2014. But not for 2012. Strange.

Answer (score -1):

```
=INT(([Report Date]-DATE(YEAR([Report Date]),1,1)+(TEXT(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR([Report Date]),1,1)),"d")))/7)+1
```

Comment: Please provide a descriptive answer so it will be useful to the forum.